# Vite and Vue3 loading dynamic using meta.glob fails on prod mode

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I try to load the components dynamically with Vite and Vue3, so that components are not loaded at all, which are not used. This works fine in DEV mode, but as soon as I run npm run build, the components can not be loaded, because Vite does not resolve the paths correctly.

this is my main.js File

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent  } from 'vue'
import App from '@/App.vue'

const components = Object.assign(
    import.meta.glob("./components/**/*.vue"),
    import.meta.glob("./widgets/**/*.vue")
)

for (const k in components) {
    const name = k.split("/").pop().replace('.vue', '');
    app.component(name, defineAsyncComponent(() => import(k)));
}
```

So the Components loaded from the path ./components/input/input.vue and added to components by its filename.

After I run npm run build, Vite generates minified files addet in the dist/assets Folder which looks like: input.a08d9c39.js

When I do a console.log to components, it tries to load it from the same path as in dev mode so ./components/input/input.vue, which is not correct in prod mode.

I'm not sure if the vite.config.js file is needed for a solution, nevertheless this is the file.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],

    resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: What are you expecting the component paths to be in prod mode?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much there except that you can't pass a variable to an `import()` function.

Fortunately, you don't need to, since you already have the imported component render function available:

```js
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

export const asyncComponents = {
    install: (app) => {
        const components = import.meta.glob("../components/async/**/*.vue");

        for (const filePath in components) {
            const name = filePath.split("/").pop().replace('.vue', '');

            app.component(
                name,
                defineAsyncComponent(() => components[filePath])
            );
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: For me I had to do `defineAsyncComponent(components[filePath])` if I wrap it in a function I get a vue error that `loader().catch` is not a function